# benefits of aws ebs snapshot versus sc1 "cold" hhd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have some data that I want to backup. sc1 cold storage costs $0.025/GB/month while a snapshot costs $0.05/GB/month. What is the advantage of a snapshot over just keeping my data on a sc1 hhd?

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon EBS Snapshot can be used to restore volumes. They are incremental in nature, so sequential snapshots do not require (nor charge for) a complete snapshot.

If you are wanting to backup data, I would recommend Amazon S3. Combined with [Amazon S3 Intelligent-Tiering — a New Amazon S3 Storage Class](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-intelligent-tiering/), storage costs can be as low as $0.0125 per GB.

For pure backups that are rarely accessed, S3 Glacier Deep Archive (coming soon) is under $0.001/GB.